# e.PreventDefault is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have registerAjax(e) function:

```
function registerAjax(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let userData = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
};
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
    headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
    data: userData,
    success: registerSuccess,
    error: handleAjaxError
});
function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
    saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
    showInfo('User registration successful.');
}
```

This function is invoked by this function

```
function registerUser() {
registerAjax();
```

When i run the app, i recieve the console message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined(…)"

Is There any easy solution for fix this exception ?

```
function startApplication() { 
  //Bind The Form Submit Buttons 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnRegister").on('click', registerUser()); 
  });
  loadingBox(); 
  //Bind the info / error boxes: hide on click 
  $("#infoBox, #errorBox").click(function () { 
    $(this).fadeOut(); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Why would there be an event when you don't pass any?

Comment: Why would you call preventDefault on undefined?

Comment: I'm new in this so, how can i register user succesfully ?

Comment: What "default" are you trying to "prevent"?  You don't pass anything to the `registerAjax()` function.  It sounds like `e.preventDefault()` is the result of some code you copied and pasted and you don't actually need it.

Comment: Yea, but without this preventDefault() when i load the Register page, the functionality isn't working, so i can't register user

Comment: @RumenPanchev: And *with* `e.preventDefault()` it also "isn't working".  So it would seem that randomly adding that line of code didn't fix whatever problem you were originally having.  But none of us know what that problem was.

Comment: Here i invoke the regusterUser function

function startApplication() {
    //Bind The Form Submit Buttons
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnRegister").on('click', registerUser());
    });
    loadingBox();

    //Bind the info / error boxes: hide on click
    $("#infoBox, #errorBox").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
}

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
$("#btnRegister").on('click', registerUser());
```

This invokes `registerUser()` *immediately* and sets the click handler to the *return value* of `registerUser()`, which doesn't return anything.  I suspect you want this:

```
$("#btnRegister").on('click', registerUser);
```

The function name itself can be used as a variable to represent the function when passing it to a handler.  (Or when doing much of anything with the function, short of invoking it.  In JavaScript a function is a type like any other and can be passed around like any variable.)

**Additionally**, you'll need to pass the event through to your other function.  By default, the click handler will be passed the event, so you can use it:

```
function registerUser(e) {
    // e is your event
}
```

In your case, you'd want to pass it along to your other function:

```
function registerUser(e) {
    registerAjax(e);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Mind blown this gets downvoted. SO can be unbelievable sometimes.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm: I'm trying to see if I perhaps misunderstood the question, though as of yet don't notice the problem.  Either way, one should never take downvotes personally.

Comment: No the OP clearly doesn't understand how `event` gets passed, which you explained. I had an answer similar, although not as elaborate as yours and it was downvoted. Ended up deleting it, rather not eat 2 points just because someone is deciding to be an asshat today.

Comment: Doh! I just made the same mistake. Thanks for the timely slap upside the head!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `registerUser` reference instead of calling it:

```
$("#btnRegister").on('click', registerUser);
```

And add `event` parameter to `registerUser`:

```
function registerUser(e) {
  registerAjax(e);
  ...
}
```